# Stylize new row for DataGrid with CanUserAddRows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to stylize a **row** in `DataGrid` for `CanUserAddRows`.
`ItemsSource` for `DataGrid` i use `DataTable.DefaultView`
I try:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="false" CanUserAddRows="True">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding='{Binding Path=Col1}' Header="Col1" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding='{Binding Path=Col2}' Header="Col2" />
    <!-- more columns -->
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But **new row** not **tomato** color =(
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for this question!

Need **.NET FrameWork 4.5**

set **Trigger.Property=IsNewItem** and **Trigger.Value=true** :

```
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsNewItem" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Tomato"/>
              </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
```